How to compute the density of this alternate proposal?
Introduction
In my particle filtering application, I have an alternative proposal (an importance function) that seems to improve performance, measured by posterior probability of the estimated states. But I'm unsure of the correct expression for the importance density, which divides particle weights in the Sequential Importance Resampling (SIR) algorithm.
At a high level, we have uniform time series of observations, and we are inferring variable length segments, composed of the conditional density $p_C(\mathbf{x}_{k} \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$ (described below).
Here I am being vague on some of the details, which I believe mostly irrelevant to the main issue: understanding how to normalize (or just getting more insight into) this alternative proposal.
State Space and Prior
The state at time $k$ is $\mathbf{x}_k$. It is a tuple containing some continuous variables (not described), and $j_k$, a binary indicator if we will start a new segment at time $k$.
In the simpler version of this, there are 2 continuous variables.
The prior is composed from two distributions, $p_I(\mathbf{x})$ representing either an initial state or a new segment, and $p_C(\mathbf{x}_{k} \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$ representing a continued segment.
$p_I(\mathbf{x})$ has a simple structure, a Gaussian in one dimension and Uniform in the other dimension. Very diffuse, it represents "start from anywhere".
$p_C(\mathbf{x}_{k} \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$ is much more compact, a conditional Gaussian with some light non-linearity.
To sample from the prior, we draw $j_k$ from a Bernoulli variable (with probability $p_J$), and draw the remaining components from either $p_I$ or $p_C$ depending on its result.
Likelihood
Here, I will be the most vague. The likelihood $p(\mathbf{y}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_k)$ is multimodal, there are peaks in multiple places in the 2D plane. In one dimension, there are irregular multiples, and in the other dimension, there are regular multiples.
Alternative Proposals: where to start?
The bootstrap filter uses a default proposal of $p(\mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$, but sources suggest we can do better.
One common suggestion is to use the likelihood function $p(\mathbf{y}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_k)$, but we want to maintain the segmentation behavior from the prior. Here, we try to incorporate likelihood information into a proposal similar to the prior.
Proposal: Smart Segments
Instead of sampling the segmentation variable blindly and with fixed probability $p_J$, we sample candidates from both $p_I$ and $p_C$, and evaluate their likelihoods to try to get a smarter probability for segmentation.
That is, we sample: $\mathbf{x}_I \sim p_I(\mathbf{x})$,
and $\mathbf{x}_C \sim p_C(\mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$.
Then, we score: $s_I := p(\mathbf{y}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_I) \cdot p_J$,
and $s_C := p(\mathbf{y}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_C) \cdot (1 - p_J)$.
This gives us a new Bernoulli probability: $p_S := \frac{s_I}{s_I + s_C}$.
Finally, we draw $j_k$ from a Bernoulli with parameter $p_S$ and set the remaining components of $\mathbf{x}_k$, from either $\mathbf{x}_I$ or $\mathbf{x}_C$, depending on $j_k$.
Attempt at computing density
SIR needs us to compute $\pi(\mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}_k)$ for our generated samples to divide our weights.
We could try something like:
$\hat{\pi}(\mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}_k) :=
\begin{cases}
p_S \cdot p_I(\mathbf{x}_k), & \text{if } j_k = 1, \\
(1 - p_S) \cdot p_C(\mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}), & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$
But, $p_S$ is not fixed, not a part of the state $\mathbf{x}_k$, and not an argument to the importance function $\pi$. It was generated through the intermediate variables $x_I$ and $x_C$, suggesting there are multiple paths to $\mathbf{x}_k$ and some integration is necessary.
Questions

What is the real density $\pi$?
What can I do to numerically check my estimate?
If this is bad, is there some low complexity better estimate?


I think there is too little information about ${\bf y}_k$ here. Is it observable? Are you just making it up? With the given information it looks like we can't say anything about how ${\bf x}_k$ and the "real" $\pi$ depend on ${\bf y}_k$. Also you don't say explicitly what you ultimately want to estimate.

You have put a changepoint tag on this.  Have you looked at the Bayesian changepoint / hidden markov model literature?  If not, I can dig some references that show different approaches out for you.

@adunaic Perhaps the changepoint tag was rash, I have removed it. I have some primer-level knowledge as a user of changepoint methods. The segmentation is performed in the state space (jointly with the inverse problem), so I don't know if changepoint methods are directly applicable. Similarly, the inference is in a continuous space with no fixed finite states, so I don't think discrete HMMs are directly applicable. Though both are definitely inspirations since they segment things. If you have any relevant references, I would love to see them.

Hi @ChristianHennig. It is an application from signal processing. I think it is not observable, there are multiple matches in state space for a single point in observation space. I added a bit more detail on the likelihood. Thank you for your questions.

Since asking my question here (and to a few others), and simplifying the problem, I think I have an answer to my question. The answer uses basic probability, but it took me a while to find my bearings as I was a bit rusty.
A toy problem: 1d Gaussians
How to sample from $p_C(x)$:
$a \sim p_A(x), \quad b \sim p_B(x),$
$s(a,b) := \frac{f(a)}{f(a)+f(b)},$
$d \sim \text{Ber}\left( s(a,b) \right),$
$c := \begin{cases} 
a, & \text{if } d = 1,\\  
b, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$
Once $a$ and $b$ are fixed, this gives us the following conditional  discrete distribution:
$P(c \mid A=a, B=b) = $



c
P(c|a,b)




$a$
$s(a,b)$


$b$
$1 - s(a,b)$



Since we want $P(c)$ without conditionals, we can use the law of total probability, and so we marginalize over $a$ and $b$:
$$P(c) = \iint P(c \mid A=a, B=b) \, p_B(b) \, p_A(a) \, da \, db.$$
This integral seems tricky because the mass positions are not fixed. It turns out to be a sum of two single integrals (one for each mass in the discrete distribution):
$$P(c) = \int s(c,b) \, p_B(b) \, p_A(c) \, db + 
\int (1 - s(a,c)) \, p_B(c) \, p_A(a) \, da.$$
If we have $N$ pairs of samples $(a_i,b_i)$ from $p_A$ and $p_B$, we can build an approximation by treating each integral as an expectation (over $p_B$, and over $p_A$):
$$\hat{P}(c) = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i s(c,b_i) \, p_A(c) +
\frac{1}{N} \sum_i (1 - s(a_i,c)) \, p_B(c). $$
In a simulation experiment with two Gaussians as $p_A$ and $p_B$, the Riemann approximation, as well as the Monte Carlo approximation seem to conform very well to a kernel density estimate (KDE) of an empirical distribution.

Joint distribution with $d$, when we know the indicator for which distribution
In this case, this is only slightly more complicated. The updated table for the discrete distribution is:



c
d
P(c|a,b)




$a$
1
$s(a,b)$


$b$
0
$1 - s(a,b)$



The joint distribution $P(c,d)$ is simply the individual integrals split from the marginal distribution $P(c)$:
$$P(c,d=1) = \int s(c,b) \, p_B(b) \, p_A(c) \, db,$$
$$P(c,d=0) = \int (1 - s(a,c)) \, p_B(c) \, p_A(a) \, da.$$
The original problem, by analogy
Since we just have to swap the distributions $p_A$ and $p_B$ for $p_I$ and $p_C(\mathbf{x} \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1})$, the importance density should have the following form:
$$\pi(\mathbf{x}_k, j_k = 1 \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}) =
\int s( \mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{x}_C ) \, 
p_C( \mathbf{x}_C \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1} ) \,
p_I( \mathbf{x}_k ) \, d\mathbf{x}_C,$$
$$\pi(\mathbf{x}_k, j_k = 0 \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}) =
\int (1 - s( \mathbf{x}_I, \mathbf{x}_k )) \, 
p_C( \mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1} ) \,
p_I( \mathbf{x}_I ) \, d\mathbf{x}_I.$$
Above, I am using $s(,)$ for the function that assigns Bernoulli probabilities, and not showing its implicit dependence of $\mathbf{y}$.
The main difference from the previous sections is that the state variables (we are integrating over) have more dimensions.
If we have $N$ samples of both distributions $(\mathbf{x}_{I,i}, \mathbf{x}_{C,i})$, we could form the approximations:
$$\hat{\pi}(\mathbf{x}_k, j_k=1 \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}) =
\frac{1}{N} \sum_i s( \mathbf{x}_k, \mathbf{x}_{C,i} ) \, 
p_I( \mathbf{x}_k ),$$
$$\hat{\pi}(\mathbf{x}_k, j_k=0 \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1}, \mathbf{y}) =
\frac{1}{N} \sum_i (1 - s(\mathbf{x}_{I,i}, \mathbf{x}_k)) \,
p_C( \mathbf{x}_k \mid \mathbf{x}_{k-1} ).
$$
Conclusions
This matches the formula in the "Attempt at computing density" section, i.e. it fits the Monte Carlo estimate with N=1. Using more samples in line with the formula should improve the estimate of density.
Not shown: some noisy plots of the original estimate as a density estimate.
Here, we have found the true density and some form of estimating it. However, it would be great to read any references on proposals like these in importance sampling and particle filtering.
